# Cannot connect to https domain in ios issue

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I have an application designed in xamarin.ios that is supposed to download an `ipa` file remotely and install it on the iphone. I am making this happen programmatically as follows:

```
   string url = "https://cielgroup.github.io/apps/TruckApp.iOS.plist";
   NSString stringUrl =  new NSString("itms-services://?action=download-manifest&url="+url);
   NSUrl fileUrl = new NSUrl(stringUrl);
   success = UIApplication.SharedApplication.CanOpenUrl(fileUrl); // returns true
   UIApplication.SharedApplication.OpenUrl(fileUrl);
```

The `boolean` success returns `true` which means that it can open the `URL`. But the app does not crash, it just shows an alert message :

> Cannot connect to cielgroup.github.io

However, when I put the below code embedded in a web page and host it onthe same domain and access the `URL` through the browser of the iphone, it works. That is, the `ipa` file is downloaded and installed successfully on the iphone.

```
<a href="itms-services://?action=download-manifest&url=https://cielgroup.github.io/TruckApp.iOS.plist">
  Download Application
</a>
```

Could someone please help to rectify this issue when doing this programmatically using `NSURL`? Do I have to add anything in the `Info.plist` ? Please help.

Answer (score 0):

The problem might be that the file is not accessible outside your network. Just my guess since I just tried to open the page `https://cielgroup.github.io/apps/TruckApp.iOS.plist` and its telling me the page cannot be found. So try this. Go on your phone and take yourself off the network and use your cellular data plan. See if the file can download. If it cannot download then its an issue with the url not being public. The function might be returning true since your on the network and and your accessing an intranet URL. Let me know how it goes.

Comment: Hi Esko918. I have modified the `URL` since I am not supposed to make it public. The file is downloaded when accessed via a browser. All works fine in the browser of the iphone.

Comment: Yea but your supposed to make it accessible to anyone using the url correct? So you have to make it so people can at least hit the url and probably put in some sort of username and password then give them access to the file. Think of it this way, im a random user who wants to download the file. How can I do that unless the URL is public? You do want people who don't have access to your intranet to download the file correct?

Comment: Did you do what I asked you to do? Which was take a phone and go on your cellular network. If your able to download the file then its something else. If your not it sounds like an accessibility issue. I know your saying you don't want to make it public. Yet, if you want Joe Schmo to be able to download the file then you have to make it public. Which is why I said you can put some sort of username/password login to be able to download the app.

Answer (score 0):

It is important to understand that `canOpenURL` simply checks that there is a handler for the specified URL on the device; so, in this case you are asking "can `itms-services` urls be opened?"  It doesn't check for 
connectivity to or availability of the resource specified by the URL.

You need to percent encode the `url` before you use it in `stringUrl`

Comment: Hello. Could you please advise further on percent encode the `url` ?  

My guess is that something is missing in the code or some permission is required in the `Info.plist`. That's what I am not sure of. 

Because when I access the same `url` in the device's browser, the app is downloaded and installed correctly.

Comment: @ExpertGenie Theres a third party library. Really its just a function or 2. That does percent escaping for you. I forgot its name but you can just look up percent escaping and you should find it. Its also accessible via cocoa pods